# What do certain symbols between '/''s mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

I found these, but I am too new to programming to understand this properly. Also, you can't really google this stuff:

```
/SUFIX ([\[\]\w]+)/i
/ENEMY ([^>,;]+)/i
/RED ([+-]?\d+)/i
```

I know they have to do with strings, and I'm pretty sure that the `"/i"` means the characters can be any-case, but I have no clue what the rest could mean.

Could anyone explain what these do, or link me to documentation? Hopefully this isn't custom symbols or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That defines a *regular expression*, which you can use to match text or perform advanced substitutions. You'll find a lot more detail on the [Ruby documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html).

Answer (score 0):

At a quick glance, here's what the patterns mean:

```
/SUFIX ([\[\]\w]+)/i
```

This is looking for some text like one of these:

```
SUFIX [123]
sufix [abc]
SuFiX [a1]
SUFIX [foo_bar]
SUFIX [1]
```

but won't match:

```
SUFIX []
```

This:

```
/ENEMY ([^>,;]+)/i
```

Looks for:

```
ENEMY foo
enemy bar
Enemy 123foo456bar
```

but won't match anything with `>`, `,` or `;` following it:

```
ENEMY >
ENEMY ,
ENEMY ;
```

would all fail.

This:

```
/RED ([+-]?\d+)/i
```

Would be happy with:

```
RED 1
red +10
ReD -5
```

And unhappy with anything that wasn't an optional `+`/`-` followed by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

One of the better way to learn regex is to use something like http://www.rubular.com/
Rubular is a Ruby-based regular expression editor. It's a handy way to test regular expressions as you write them.